# All c++ code turned red after shifting SDK folder to different directory (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

```
18:37   C/C++ Configuration Problem
        native-lib | debug | x86
        Cannot run program ""D:\Android" (in directory "E:\android studio projects\sampleopengl\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\x86"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I recently changed the directory of my android sdk to clear space in my c drive. My c++ code completely turned red, its showing unknown types, undeclared symbols. When i run the app it runs just fine but none of the c++ files are recognized by android studio.

Comment: First thing to check would probably be to make sure that all makefiles / build scripts / configuration files that may contain references to the SDK/NDK path are updated. After that, make sure that you're only using paths that don't contain any spaces.

Comment: Paths containing spaces usually are not an issue for cmake. Not sure about the build system used here though. Regarding the question though: Have you set up the project again or at least cleared the relevant entires from the cmake cache before reconfiguring the project? Often some info about lib locations is stored in cache variables and cmake checks, if these variables are set to avoid repeating the search unnecessarily which can result in cmake not picking up modified library locations.

Comment: I changed the sdk folder name and the error was resolved .